# Version problems running Subclipse and TortoiseSVN

Tags: c#, tortoisesvn, subclipse

I have Subclipse installed for Java and just installed TortoiseSVN for #develop, as suggested by someone answering another question of mine.  When I try to edit a C# class, it says "client is too old to work with working copy" - but the Subversion version of TortoiseSVN (1.5) seems to be newer than that of Subclipse (1.4?). What is going on - the message seems a bit backwards! Can I downgrade the version level of TortoiseSVN to match Subclipse, or upgrade Subclipse?!  Suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my problem was due to the fact that #develop 2.2 forces TortoiseSVN 1.4 - it does not work with TortoiseSVN 1.5.  Oh well!  Thanks for your feedback anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Straight from the [FAQ](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#clientold):

> The full error message is: This client is too old to work with working copy '.'; please get a newer Subversion client.

You will get this error message once you have used a Subversion client linked with a higher Subversion version, and then try to execute a command with a Subversion client linked with an older version, e.g., you used an 1.4.x client on your working copy, and now you try an svn 1.3.x client on the same working copy.

The reason for this is that Subversion 1.4 and 1.5 upgrade the working copies transparently on every command. But once the working copy format is upgraded, older clients can't access the working copy anymore because they don't know the new format.

The only solution to 'fix' this is to upgrade whatever client you use and that gave you this error message. Or do a fresh checkout with the older client.

Answer (score 0):

The message is correct. You have two SVN clients: TortoiseSVN and Subclipse. The Subclipse client is too old to work with the TortoiseSVN working copy. As part of the changes for subversion 1.5, the format of the working copy was modified to support the new merge tracking feature. If you access your working copy with TortoiseSVN, it will be automatically converted from the v1.4 format to the newer v1.5 format (this is mentioned in the TortoiseSVN and Subversion release notes).

So, if you are going to use both Subclipse and TortoiseSVN on the same working copy, you'll want both clients to either be based on compatible subversion versions (ie. both on subversion 1.4.x or both based on subversion 1.5.x). So you should either upgrade Subclipse, or downgrade TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Subversive it's now the official Subversion Eclipse plugin.

[1] : http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/